# How to force tesseract not to use TESSDATA_PREFIX

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I had tesseract installed on my pc, and it defined TESSDATA_PREFIX enviroment variable.  After complete uninstallation of tesseract, i try to use tesseract API in this way:

```
if (myOCR->Init("C:/Projects/project/Release/tessdata/", "rus")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

and recieve

```
Error opening data file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/rus.traine
ddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent d
irectory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'rus'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

typing set TESSDATA_PREFIX in cmd gives me that there is no such variable. But tesseract remembers it (don't know how). So how can i force tesseract to search traindata in concrete folder? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This seems helpful:
[Tesseract - change language file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950977/tesseract-change-language-file-location)

From the answer in that thread, it appears to be the case that tesseract looks for the environment variable, but *if it is not set, assumes a fixed location*.

The easiest way to fix this would be to run "cmd", then do:

```
c:\Users\alex> set TESSDATA_PREFIX="C:/Projects/project/Release/tessdata"
c:\Users\alex> cd MyOCRProgDir
c:\Users\alex\MyOCRProgDir> MyProg
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i don't want to use this, because it wouldn't work on another pc

Comment: 1.) i will have no opportunity to set env variable mannualy on another pc 2.) it is not convinient 3) even after reseting this variable, i dont know why, but it searches in C:\Progamfiles (x86)\tesseract-ocr ...

Comment: i made full reg scan and deleted all when i met TESSDATA_PREFIX, but it searches in old directory

Comment: Firstly, you will put these commands into a "Batch file" (a file with .bat extension) and when you copy your program onto the other computer(s), you'll also copy this .bat file onto their Desktop, making it a "shortcut" that they double-click to launch your OCR program.

Secondly, since this did not work, is there any chance you could build Tesseract from source? I know it sounds involved, but if you can do that, you may be able to use the advice on the thread I pointed you to.

Comment: in this case you can use putenv right from the code rather than bat file. Anyway reboot solves this tricky problem with enviroment variable previously defined by tesseract exe. Thanks

Comment: All it needed was a reboot? Hah! Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ive been through the same problem . .. All I did was copy the tessdata folder to the directory where my application is running . . .

Note: after doing so make sure to set that the tessdata properties "Copy to Output Directory"  to "Copy Always" . This solves the problem . . .

Refer to this link in youtube . . .for better demonstration . . .Hope it helps :)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqvvXJXuRYY

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with training data. Instead of forcing not to use TESSDATA_PREFIX, I found a workaround. This worked for me.

My machine is 64 bit and im building a 32 bit copy with VS2012.

set the environment variables.
TESSDATA_PREFIX : C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR

here "Tesseract-OCR" is the parent directory of "tessdata" folder.

edit the path variable.
path : C:\tess\lib\lib;

here "C:\tess\lib\lib" is the place where lib and dll files are located : liblept168.dll,liblept168.lib etc.

start a new win32 console application and set the following settings.
C/C++ >> General
    C:\tess\include\include

here "C:\tess\include\include" is the parent directory of "tesseract" and "leptonica" folders where the include files are located.

Linker >> Additional Library Dependencies
    C:\tess\lib\lib

Linker >> Additional Dependencies
    liblept168.lib
    libtesseract302.lib
    (add these to the list)

C/C++>>Preprocessor
    _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS (add this to the list)

copy the two tesseract dlls (corresponding to the library files) to debug and release folders (not the ones inside the root)

copy the tessdata folder (inside the Tesseract installation) to the locations mentioned above.

Hopefully, You will be good to go.